# How should a simple Qt C++ status class be made accessible from both C++ and QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I’m new to QT and QML.  I have a status class that holds a single QString property with the needed signals and slots.  This property is displayed in the footer section of the main Page QML object.  I can make the status object available in the QML by using “engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty” in the main.cpp file.
My question is what is the **RECOMMENDED WAY** to make a class like "status" accessible everywhere throughout my (QML and C++) application??

Should I use make everything in the status class static?

Should I make the status class instance global? If so, will that interfere with the QML?

Should I pass a reference to every place the status needs to be accessed from? Which is almost everywhere.

Does Qt already have some helper classes and or structured way that I should be using?

Any assistance and sample code or example would be greatly appreciated.

status.h

```
#define STATUS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Status : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString status READ status WRITE setStatus NOTIFY statusChanged)

public:
    explicit Status(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString status();

signals:
    void statusChanged ();

public slots:
    void setStatus (QString);

private:
    QString m_Status;
};

#endif // STATUS_H
```

status.c

```
#include "status.h"

Status::Status(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    m_Status = "No Status Info";
}

QString Status::status()
{
    return m_Status;
}

void Status::setStatus(QString newStatus)
{
    if (m_Status != newStatus)
    {
        m_Status = newStatus;
        emit statusChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need single and global status instance, making it singleton solves this problem.

Comment: When people ask for the "recommended way" to do something, it always ends up sounding like they're asking for an opinion, which is not what this site is for.

Comment: 1. setContextProperty (as you've found), 2. qmlRegisterSingletonType (As Galib mentioned). But, you're not limited to these, it depends on your use case, as you could be considering Q_GADGET vs Q_OBJECT. You could be considering factory objects, You could be thinking is C++ really needed if you can leverage QML more?